# jQuery model form does not store data in the database

Tags: java, jquery-ui

I am trying to add the form data to the database in java -- using jQuery model form dialog to create a form -- but I cannot see any data in my database.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class newUserServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/newUserServ")
public class newUserServlet extends HttpServlet {

    Connection connection;

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {

        try{

            Class.forName("org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver");

                                    //my database connection url                
            connection=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","kavuri654");

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String username =request.getParameter("name");
        String email =request.getParameter("email");
        String password =request.getParameter("password");

          PrintWriter out =response.getWriter();

        out.println("<h3>added<h3>");

        try{
            String selectQuery="insert into test.newuser(name,email,password)"+"values(?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement preparedstatement=connection.prepareStatement(selectQuery);
            preparedstatement.setString(1, username);
            preparedstatement.setString(2, email);
            preparedstatement.setString(3, password);

            int i =preparedstatement.executeUpdate();

            if(i>0){
                System.out.println("one row is added");
            }

            connection.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }






    }

}
```

I created a servlet to handle the request sent from the web client. In this servlet, I added the database connection details and I am reading the form data using request object and by using setter methods values are being stored into the database. I am able to add the details to the form but the form data is not stored in database. What should I do to store my form data into the database.

Answer (score 1):

There would be some reasons.

1. Firstly check if your data "arrive" to this Servlet.
2. If 1 is ok then you should commit your statement : connection.commit()

Answer (score 0):

Your servlet is ok. First I've created a mysql database test and added the table newuser:

```
create table newuser (
    name varchar(255),
    email varchar(255),
    password varchar(255)
)
```

Then I've created a maven jetty project with your code in it. Then I opened following url in the browser:

```
http://localhost:8899/newUserServ?name=testname&email=testemail&password=testpwd
```

And voila - the record appeared in the table.